# MySQL LEFT JOIN in CASE?

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I want to join different tables depending on the value of one column, like so (this doesn't work, but it's my example):

`SELECT * FROM table1
JOIN (CASE WHEN table1_column1=1 THEN table2 ON table2_column1=table1_column2 END)
WHERE table1_column3='hello'`

All in all there are gonna be 4 values in the column, calling other tables. Is this doable?

Edit: I think I need to clarify what I'm after. Depending on the value of table1_column1, I want the JOIN to fetch a specific table and column. For example, if t1c1=1 it should join table2_column1 on table1_column2. If, however, t1c1=2 it should join table5_column1 on table1_column2. Etc, etc, etc.

Again - is this doable? It's easily scripted if I use two separate queries. I just want to use one query, however.

Comment: And how do you see the result set? Do you realize that if it worked in that way - then different rows would contain different amount of columns

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
table1 JOIN table2 ON table2_column1=table1_column2 AND table1_column1=1

UNION

 SELECT * FROM 
table1 JOIN table3 ON table2_column1=table1_column2 AND table1_column3='hello'
```

it might work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
JOIN  table2 ON table2_column1=table1_column2 and table1_column1=1 
WHERE table1_column3='hello'
```